# How to sort custom column for WordPress users on a key that not all users have?

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to set-up a sortable column in my users section of my WordPress admin.

I have a custom meta field for the user call `last_shipped_item` and it contains a date/time string.

Since not all users have bought something from the site, there may be not meta key for some users.

How can I set up the field to be sortable so that in my users section, I can sort by the users who most recently had something shipped?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
function site_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    
    global $ticus_states, $ticus_relationships, $ticus_disciplines, $ticus_experience;
        
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'lastpurchased' :
            $meta = get_the_author_meta( 'last_shipped_item', $user_id );
            if (!$meta) {
                return '-';
            }
            return wp_date("F j, Y, g:i a", $meta); 
            break;
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'site_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );

function site_modify_user_sortable_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['lastpurchased'] = 'lastpurchased';

    //To make a column 'un-sortable' remove it from the array unset($columns['date']);

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'site_modify_user_sortable_column' );

add_action("pre_get_users", function ($WP_User_Query) {

    if ( isset($WP_User_Query->query_vars["orderby"]) && ("lastpurchased" === $WP_User_Query->query_vars["orderby"]) ) {
        $WP_User_Query->query_vars["meta_key"] = "last_shipped_item";
        $WP_User_Query->query_vars["meta_query"] = array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'last_shipped_item',                 
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            )
        );
        $WP_User_Query->query_vars["orderby"] = "meta_value";
    }

}, 10, 1);
```

Any thoughts on what needs to be done to make the custom column sortable?